# Debug T4 Template Disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2015, t4

After I step into my T4 template, and then stop the debugger I am unable to select 'debug t4 template' after right clicking on my tt file.  I have to restart vs.net to see that option enabled.
I am using vs.net 2015 on x64 windows 8 pc.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it looks like Visual Studio has finished running the code (due to the debugging tools becoming disabled), it is still running. Click the stop debug button and you will get something like this:

[image]

Click Yes and Robert's your Father's brother.